# How to connect my real device to android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I have installed Flutter plugin on Android Studio and I want to connect my Huawei phone to it but I just couldn't . I tried all of following solutions but none of them worked:

-Making sure that USB debugging and developer options are on.
-Downloaded usb driver, and I also checked downloading Google usb driver
-Did all the solutions of go to Project Structure and change the SDK to the latest (API 30).
-flutter/bin path and all those stuff are in environmental changes .

Not to mention how many videos I watched about it .

But still I can't connect my device to Android Studio to run the first flutter app .

Comment: When you run `flutter doctor` on terminal, does it return any red X?

Comment: No everything is good except the exclamation mark  besides Connected devices [ No devices available ].

Answer (score 2):

This answer is written based on the Windows-7 operating system. But these steps would work in any other similar windows versions, 8, 8.1, or 10.

How to check whether my device is identified
Go to your SDK installed location. Usually it will be something like, C:\Users\Dodan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Go to platform-tools directory and start your command prompt from there,

(Shift+Right click -> Open Command window here)

then type “adb devices” and press enter.

If your device is identified, you will see a message similar to the following

List of devices attached

179f84b5 device

If you cannot see a device there, try the following possible solutions. Remember to re-do this step after trying each solution to identify whether your device was identified.

Possible Solutions

1. Make sure USB Debugging is enabled in your device
   This option is usually available under settings -> developer options menu of your phone. Make sure the tick is on.
2. Make sure you have installed the android sdk
   You can find the sdk from the following link. If you have not installed it, download and install it from here, http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

Usually this takes about 3GB of space from your hard disk

3. Install the Android USB drivers for your phone
   Make sure to download the installer from the original manufacturer. Most other alternatives will make your life even harder.

For example, for samsung devices, you can install the original software from the from the following link.

http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117

4. Install Google USB Driver
   For this first you have to start the SDK manager from your computer. It will be installed usually in the following location.

C:\Users<User Account>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\SDK Manager.exe

Run it!

In the “Extras” section of the SDK manager, you will find an option named, “Google USB Driver”. Select it and install it.

5. Install a device software
   This is not the same as the Android USB drivers. For samsung, it is the Kies software. For HTC, it will be the HTC Sync Manager. Similarly, install the software related to your device brand.

Usually your device connects to the computer as an MTP device. Sometimes, changing it to Camera(PTP) or Mass Storage(USM) solves the issue.

6. Configure/Change Media Mode
   Right click “My Computer” and click “Manage”.

From the Computer Management window, select, “Device Manager”

You will see your device under “other devices”, “Portable devices” or “Universal Serial Bus Controllers”.

Right click and select the update driver option.

8. Configure Knox security settings
   If your device is a samsung s6, you should additionally enable knox configurations listed under, settings->Security
9. Try Swapping USB ports and cables
   Sounds weird! But this has proven to be the problem many people had. Try plugging your device to different ports, or try using different cables. Some cables may either be incompatible or damaged.
10. Retry!
    I know that sounds bad. But, if any of those options does not work, you can either try restarting your machine, or reinstalling all the software, including android studio and the sdk, well may be, a different version.